# Is there a way to connect a 51mm silencer to a 23mm downpipe

Tags: exhaust, fabrication

I have a tgb r 125x can't find full sport exhaust or down pipe,wondering if it is possible to weld a 51mm slip on silencer if I cut silencer off one piece exhaust and reuse down pipe which is only 23mm.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The obvious answer is: yes. You just need to transition it from one to the other. How you make that happen is up to your imagination. You won't hurt anything by doing such, but aesthetics may be compromised. If you're not too worried about how it looks, shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, design a cone with the two diameters to match the ones you state.

Then put a cut line to open it out flat and you have a template to use to cut the sheet metal so you can fold it.

In fact, a classic engineering design drawing exercise...

Depending on the space you have, then the minimum losses is with an included angle of about 6.5 degrees... But also consider using a flat plate could cause odd behavior in terms of pressure effects.